# How do I get a field value in a template?

Tags: theming

I want to change the default HTML for a custom field called *field_product_image* and I created the field--field_product_image.html.twig template. Now I need to fill in the following information in the HTML, but for some reason I cannot get the content of the fields.

```
<img src="{{ TWIG }}" alt="{{ TWIG }}" />
```

I tried different suggestions like `{{ content }}`, `{{ field.field_product_image }}`, `{{ field.field_product_image.value }}`, `{{ content.field_product_image }}`, `{{ content.uri.value  }}` but they don't output the image link.

Comment: Retrieving the links or raw text is usually a bit more complicated than just rendering the field itself.  You'll probably want to enable kint so you can kint() the vars out.  You'll probably end up doing something like: {{ field.field_product_image.0['#attr'].href }} or something really convoluted.  It depends on what the field type is and if there is any nesting, etc.

Comment: @cchoe1 thanks, i'm just starting with Drupal and thought I could just get the value from the fields name with 'node.' or 'content.'. Do you perhaps have a name or search term?

Comment: Had to test this out since I don't ever remember the exact keys required.  Do note that this is using the rendered Image display formatter--keys will change if you use something like 'URL to image'.   So assuming this is an Image field attached directly to a node w/ a single value (no unlimited cardinality) you might be able to retrieve the uri using: `{{ content.field_product_image.0['#item'].entity.uri.value }}`.  The alt may be retrieved using `{{ content.field_product_image.0['#item'].alt }}`.  Notice those two are slightly different.

Comment: I'd suggest installing devel and enabling devel & kint.  Kint can be used to essentially print_r() variables passed into templates and it'll help you figure out what keys you need to print certain things out.  Keys can change depending on the field type, display formatter, cardinality, nesting, etc. so it's hard to say what the correct answer would be.  My answer above makes a few assumptions about how you setup the fields so it may or may not work 100%.  Here is a short guide on using kint https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates

Comment: Sorry, small correction:  `{{ content.field_product_image.0['#item'].entity.uri.value }}` will return an internal URI which cannot be passed directly into a `src` attribute.  You will need to do `{{ file_url(content.field_product_image.0['#item'].entity.uri.value) }}` to convert that internal URI to a src

Comment: The proper way to do this would be to preprocess this field to add the new attributes to the image tag. Rendering the image will already give you the src and alt attributes for you, so which attributes are you really trying to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to do this is to use `mytheme_preprocess_image()`.

Here is an example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_image().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['style_name'] == 'content_embed') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'custom_class';
  }

  $variables['attributes']['data-custom-attr'] = 'value';
}
```

Variables can be used to construct new values that get injected before rendered. The above would add `custom_class` to a rendered images class attribute if a specific image style is being used in this instance, and all images would receive the second attribute. Rendering the image will already give you the src and alt attributes for you, so which attributes are you really trying to add?

Reaching into render arrays in the template just leads to a ton of cruft and hard to maintain code because it's really not the place for that.

If you don't want any divs or wrapping HTML in your field, you can just add this to the field twig template:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

This would only render the field item (in this case image), which should leave you with only the image tag on the page and no containers.